# Bind falis to bind (TCP) and returns -1

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

hello i'm trying to figuring out what may cause the bind function of tcp to returns negative result.

i'm using the following code :
i create the socket once in the constructor and saves it as a protected member for (the sons of my API). the sons are Tcp and Udp.

can anyone understand why it's allocating badly?

```
API *client = new TCP(80); // creating socket
API *server = new TCP(81);

char ipServer[] = "127.0.0.1";
char buffer[] = "Do You Want?";
char answer[] = "no";
char buffer2[4096];


server->setIPAddress(ipServer);
server->bindCreator();
```

the bind function

int API::bindCreator() {

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;
memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sin.sin_port = htons(this->portNumber);
int sock = this->socketName;
int bindC = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin));

if (bindC < 0) {
    this->error();
}
return bindC;
```

}

Comment: Did you bother to check the value in `errno` or `GetLastError()` if on Windows?

Comment: im working on linux (through VM). and not how do i do it?

Comment: Start by reading the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind), it even lists the error codes that can be in `errno` if the call to `bind` fails.

Comment: how can i see in eclipse what's the error ive been given?

it just exit the system with no errors

Comment: Set a breakpoint and [run it in a debugger](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_debug_prog.htm) or print out the value.

Comment: i got no 13 which mean permission denied. how do i fix it?
which port should i use? im using 127.0.0.1 as ip for both server and client

Comment: @user3253375 Only the root user can bind to ports less than 1024, I suggest you make the port configurable and run your server on e.g. port 8080 while you're developing.

Comment: You should edit your post to include this newly acquired information, comments really are not the place for it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code and the subsequent comments you are receiving an error because usage of the port number you are specifying is restricted. If you look in `<errno.h>` you will see that error code 13 is `EACCES` meaning that access to that port number has been denied. By default some systems restrict the use of port numbers below 1024 to applications running in the context of a super user. You have three options.

1. Choose a different port number
2. Run the application as a super user.
3. Reconfigure your system and remove the restrictions of desired port numbers.

Comment: Thanks! i choose 6000 and 6004, and now i get different problem :)